# Extracting all dojo attach point values from HTML

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a saved HTML page which I've opened in notepad++. I would like to extract all the attach points out of the html file. Example from the HTML below:

```
<div class="contentBar">
    <div class="banner" style="">
        <span class="bannerRepeat"></span>
        <span class="bannerDecal"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="logo" data-dojo-attach-point="pageLogoPt">
            ABC
        </div>
        <div class="title" data-dojo-attach-point="pageTitlePt">
            ABC
        </div>
        <div class="userPane">
            <div>
                <span class="LoginCell LoginText"><span data-dojo-attach-point="welcomeBlockPt">Welcome</span>, <b data-dojo-attach-point="usernameBlockPt">User Name</b></span>
                <span widgetid="acme_Button_0" id="acme_Button_0" class="LoginCell Button" data-dojo-type="acme.Button" data-dojo-props="size: 'small'" data-dojo-attach-point="logOutButtonPt"><span widgetid="dijit_form_Button_0" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton ButtonSmall" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" role="presentation"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" id="dijit_form_Button_0" tabindex="0" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_0_label"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">&#9679;</span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_0_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Logout</span></span></span><input value="" class="dijitOffScreen" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" type="button"></span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="printLink" style="display:none;">Print</span>
                <span id="zoomPercentageDisplay"><span data-dojo-attach-point="zoomBlockPt">Zoom</span>: 100%</span>
                <span id="smallFontSizeLink" style="font-size: .8em;">A</span>
                <span id="defaultFontSizeLink" style="font-size: 1em;">AA</span>
                <span id="largeFontSizeLink" style="font-size: 1.2em;">AAA</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get:

```
pageLogoPt
pageTitlePt
welcomeBlockPt
usernameBlockPt
etc ...
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Replace `(data-dojo-attach-point="[^"]+)(?=")` with `\n\1\n`. This will put what you're looking for on separate lines.
2. Mark All based on the regex `data-dojo-attach-point="[^"]+`. Tick "Bookmark line" checkbox.
3. Search -> Bookmark -> Remove Unmarked Lines
4. Replace `data-dojo-attach-point="` with blank.

This will give you your list with each item in its own line.

Tested on Notepad++ 6.8.8.

Inspired by https://superuser.com/questions/477628/export-all-regular-expression-matches-in-textpad-or-notepad-as-a-list.

Comment: Thanks but do you know how I can use this in notepad++ to extra the attach point values? I am hoping I can do a find/replace using the regex and it will leave me with just the attach point values.

Comment: @ratsstack Just added full steps.

Comment: You Sir are a genius! :-) Thanks very much.